# Number theory proofs regarding units and orders

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hey I just came across this proof but I have no idea how to prove this.

If $u$ ∈ $U_m$ has order $n$ and ($k,n$) = 1, then $u^k$ has order n.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(u^k)^n = (u^n)^k \equiv 1 \mod m$. Suppose $(u^k)^l \equiv 1 \mod m$ for some $l\mid n$. Then $$1\equiv (u^k)^l = u^{lk} \mod m$$so $n\mid lk$, as $u$ has order $n$. But $(n,k) = 1$. So $n\mid l$, whence $l=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Use that there are $x,y$ such that $kx+ny=1$. This holds for any group $G$ and any element of finite order $x$. The formula is $$|x^k|=\frac{|x|}{(|x|,k)}$$

Comment: I don't really understand this formula. What exactly does it tell you?